# Make bash file wait for system calls made in Fortran

Tags: bash, fortran, mpi, wait

My bash script looks something like this

```
mpiexec ./fortran_bin |& tee text_file
wait

./process_output_files
```

My MPI-based Fortran program makes several synchronous system calls with `call exec_cmd(cmd,wait=.true.)`.
My problem is that `handle_output_files` only waits for `fortran_bin` to finish, but some system commands (`cmd`) are not yet done, and this messes up my output files.
How do I make `process_output_files` wait for `cmd` to finish?

### NOTES

1. I'm not sure where best to solve this problem (if there is a solution):
   within Fortran, with MPI, within Bash ...
2. `cmd` is of the form `cat out_{1..n} > out  &&  rm -f out_{1..n}`.
   I would like it to run synchronously (`wait=.false.`), because `cmd` can be time-consuming, and unrelated to the rest of the Fortran program.
3. The `wait` line in the bash script seems to have no effect.
4. I suppose you could ask the equivalent question for a C/C++ program that calls `system(some_script)`.
   But I can only find question about waiting within a C/C++ program, if the same program needs the result of the called command (e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623063/waiting-for-system-call-to-finish) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928612/wait-command-wont-wait-for-child-process-to-finish-c-cpp-c?rq=1)).

Comment: You can try `wait -n`: "waits  for any job to terminate and returns its exit status.". Another solution is to move the subprocesses outside of the Fortran program. The job script should be executed by all MPI ranks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, seems like it had a reasonable chance of working. Unfortunately I get "wait: -n: invalid option". Maybe my version is too old.

Comment: As for "moving the subprocesses outside of the Fortran program", I'm not sure how best to do that, because the Fortran program generates the commands.

Answer (score 0):

From the notes above, looks like the sub command inherit the stdout/stderr on the calling process, and do not leave any background processes behind.

If those assumptions are true, you can impose a wait until there is no more output coming from the `fortran_bin` and it's children by piping the output into `cat` (or similar). The `cat` program will not terminate until all 'fortran_bin' children (that did not redirect stderr) will finish

```
mpiexec ./fortran_bin 2>&1 3>&1 | cat
```

Possible to use tee (or other similar programs) instead of cat

Comment: Actually I'm piping the output to `tee` with `mpiexec ./fortran_bin |& tee text_file`. I edited the question to reflect this. I had no idea that may be relevant, sorry.

Is that sill different from piping to `cat`?

Comment: The impact of 'tee' and 'cat' should be the same. On surface, the children do not send output to stdout (otherwise, tee will wait) - they might be using log files for stdout/stderr. Suggesting doing 'ps -f' to see which processes are still active, and then looking for away to wait on them

Comment: You might want to try `mpiexec ./fortran_bin 2>&1 3>&1 | cat`. If the children use log files, the extra connection to stdout (fd #3) may keep the connection to cat (or tee,) active.